English horror/fantasy novel about Anglo-Saxon huscarls fighting undead Vikings in modern England
There's a band of immortal Anglo-Saxon huscarls who fought for Hereward the Wake, then in various conflicts including the Albigensian crusades (on the side of the Cathars). Their group has a name which I believe is also the title of the novel.
They're fighting undead Vikings in modern England - I think late 90s, but may be 80s or early 00s.
One of them is a Viking who converted to Christianity at sword point but refused to baptise his sword arm (he betrays them). Harold Hardrada's banner plays some kind of important role.
Published before 2008.
